# How to solve this problem with geometrical series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, geometric-series

I have this question from coursera tutorial. Howver, it has been a long time that I did nothing with maths and cannot solve this problem although I found the formula of geometric series. It is important to understand it. Therefore, I will appreciate a step by step solution and help.

> Let $s[n]=\displaystyle \frac{1}{2^n}+j\frac{1}{3^n}$.Compute $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}s[n]$.

Formula is as below but I couldn't manage to solve with complex numbers.

[image]

solution is as follows:

[image]

but I couldn't understand how 1/2 and 1/3 comes.

Comment: $\frac{1-z^{N+1}}{1-z}$ is (for $z\ne 1$) $\sum_{n=0}^N z^n$, whereas in the exercise you have $\sum_{n=1}^N z^n$.

Comment: Hi! Since you are new here, I wanted to let you know that using pictures for critical portions of the post (except diagrams, of course) is discouraged. Please learn [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write out the math.

Comment: @insipidintegrator thank you for the hint. I will consider it next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum of first $n$ terms of a geometrical series is given by
$$ S_n = a \; \frac{1-z^{n}}{1-z} $$
where $a$ is the first term. For $n \rightarrow \infty$
$$ S_\infty = \frac{a}{1-z} $$ ONLY for $|z|<1$.
Since your problem wants us to start the summation from $n=1$, rather than $n=0$, the first terms will be $1/2$ and $1/3$ respectively rather than $1$ and $1$.

Comment: It is a _must_ here to mention that $|z|\lt 1$.

Comment: Oops... I should have done that. Thanks!